# Why SVG image is not working as background image?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I want to set a svg image as background image in my React project. However the code is not working. I have tried the following ways:

```
import log_bg from './Login background.svg'

useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.background = `url(${log_bg})`
  }, [])
```

Method 2.

```
<div style = {{backgroundImage: `url(${log_bg})`}}>
      TEXT
    </div>
```

I have also tried using only background tag instead of backgroundImage. I have also tried `background: log_bg` [also backgroundImage: log_bg], but it also does not works. How to fix this?

Comment: Look at the generated DOM. What value actually gets inserted into the style attribute?

Comment: @Quentin No value is being shown in style attribute. On inspect, this is being shown:
<div style="">TEXT</div>

Comment: Sounds like it might be a problem with your bundler configuration.

Comment: @Quentin What can be a possible solution to this?

Comment: @abc can you check with svg image without space in it. like replacing space with underscore in it